# Why won't my output show up?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to angular. I am trying to make the user press a button and the output should be "clicked". However, at the moment it does nothing beside the initial setting of the "hi" output.

Java Script code (Angular JS):

```
angular.module("mainModule", [])
  .controller("mainController", function ($scope, $http, jsonFilter)
  { 
    $scope.postCall = function () {
        $scope.ngResult = "clicked";
    };
  });
```

HTML CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="json_stylesheet.css"/>  
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="json_creation_functions.js"></script>
    <title>UI for Curl method</title>   
</head>
<body onload="processFlow()" ng-app="mainModule">
<div class="sheet_column"  ng-controller="mainController" >
      <button type="button" value="Submit"  ng-click="postCall()"> Submit </button> 
      <div id="result" >
         <label ng-model = "ngResult" ng-init = "ngResult = 'hi'"> {{ngResult}}</label> 
      </div>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you have any error ? Because it's working fine on fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/9a4a861s/

Comment: where is `jsonFilter` ?

Comment: Working fine for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/VwtFyIl6BLFI4u4rHQOu?p=preview .